# Query database for value and use it in a CodeIgniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting values into a view when using the following code:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($result1['organization_answer_rating1']);exit;
```

Which is being output as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [organization_answer_rating1] => 2.7500
        )

)
```

But when using it as below it is being output as an array:

```
<table class="footable">
     <thead>
             <tr>

                 <th style="text-align:center;">Organizational Mean</th>
                 <th style="text-align:center;">Workgroup Mean</th>

             </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php

echo "<td style='text-align:center;'><span>".$result1['organization_answer_rating1']."</span></td>";
echo "<td style='text-align:center;'><span>".$result1['workgroup_answer_rating1']."</span></td>";

?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What is the reason for this? Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: hi leon can you please say what was the mistake in this

Comment: while trying to make the question a bit more readable, I had mistakenly edited your question's top code from `[organization_answer_rating1] => 2.7500`  to `[organization_answer_rating] => 2.7500`, but then reverted it back (or another editor else did).

Comment: If `$result1['organization_answer_rating1']` results in that array, then `$result1['organization_answer_rating1'][0]['organization_answer_rating1'] == 2.7500`.

Comment: you are correct but a small change that is $result1['organization_answer_rating1'][0]->['organization_answer_rating1'] == 2.7500 we have to use ->

Comment: i have one more doubt can i ask

Comment: SELECT question_no FROM `questionnaire` group by question_no
SELECT SUM(`organization_answer_rating`) as orating FROM `questionnaire` where question_no =1
SELECT SUM(`workgroup_answer_rating`) as wrating FROM `questionnaire` where question_no =1
 am having the above question how to mingle all those using foreach in codeigniter model

Answer (score 0):

You should loop the result array to form a different array eg:

```
//you have your result stored in $result1

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $result1 ) ) { //mysql_fetch_array() can also be used
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
```

Now you can access $result_array as normal array see the dimension of new array using print_r($result_array) an access it using available indexes